# Firebase node js Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=484s

And an attempt of local deploying an app gives me following error:

Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve. No targets
in firebase.json match '--only functions hosting'. If you are using PowerShell make sure you place quotes around any comma-separated lists (ex: --only "functions,firestore").

I deployed to firebase, but there is an empty screen so my code lacks something essential.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/timestamp",
      "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/timestamp', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('${Date.now()}')
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the firebase.json' file and paste the following:

```
  {
   "hosting": {
   "public": "public"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{
"hosting": {
"public": "dist/project name",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
{
"source": "**",
"destination": "/index.html"
}
]
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).